# How to connect your phone as a USB modem to kubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, usb-modem

I just downloaded kubuntu 20.04 and immediately installed the drivers with the `apt install nvidia-driver-460` command. After that, I can't connect the phone as a modem, although everything worked fine before.

I also tried to manually add a Wired Connection (because it used to look like this) from usb0 (). But the system simply does not see the phone on which modem mode is enabled

Also, I don't have another internet connection on my PC, so downloading some utilities is not an option.

Comment: If your pc has wifi, would it not be simpler to create a wifi hotspot with the phone and connect to that?

Comment: Which phone is it? Any modern Android or iOS don't work as a "modem", they work with USB tethering or as WiFi hotspots for sharing the mobile internet connection.

Comment: All of the above does not make sense. I would like to know why it worked and stopped working after installing the driver. And I would like to know how to get everything back
P.S. I'm use Android

Comment: @dodickgod What doesn't makes sense is such a question but that may well be because you're using wrong terminology. Please describe *exactly* how it used to work, what you used to do in the phone and the computer, etc. We aren't seeing and can't see what you're seeing. Please help us help you.

Comment: And a couple of observations more: (1) Please use @ChanganAuto or other when replying to comments otherwise we won't be notified and may it entirely. (2) Please add the details requested above in the question itself by editing it. As soon as I (and others) understand what's happening, me or someone else might be able to write a proper answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Before updating the drivers, it was enough for me to enable the USB modem option on my phone. After that, a new Wired Connection was immediately created on kubuntu

Comment: That is USB tethering and typically it "just works". Never seen it named like that tough in an Android phone (and it isn't, it's a USB Ethernet connection, not a mode). The Nvidia driver cannot possibly have something to do with it so, probably, a coincidence. **Is the phone recognized in other modes like file transfer?** Does it work in other computers?

Comment: Still waiting... If it works now please say so. You can even answer your own question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. My answer didn't show up for some reason, but it seems to me that it doesn't make sense to me now.